# Two select()s in jq seem to throw off current pointer

Tags: json, jq

With JSON:

```
[
    {
        "key": "1",
        "value": "one"
    },
    {
        "key": "2",
        "value": "two"
    }
]
```

And `jq`:

```
.[]|{ one: select(.key=="1").value }
```

I get expected result:

```
{
  "one": "one"
}
```

If I add a second attribute, it ends up empty:

```
.[]|{ one: select(.key=="1").value, two: select(.key=="2").value }
```

If I make the `two` attribute just to be `.`, it shows `.` has become the node selected by `select()`:

```
.[]|{ one: (select(.key=="1").value), two: . }
```

Produces:

```
{
  "one": "one",
  "two": {
    "key": "1",
    "value": "one"
  }
}
```

How do I use `select()` in a way that doesn't affect `.` ?  Or better put, what is the correct way to accomplish what I am looking for:

```
{
  "one": "one",
  "two": "two"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *correct way* in this case is:

```
from_entries | {one: ."1", two: ."2"}
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Vq6hWRzdo8)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
.|{ one: (.[]|select(.key=="1").value), two: (.[]|select(.key=="2").value) }
```

The array needed to be sent through as one stream.  Using `.[]|` caused two separate streams one for each element of the array.

This is clear by doing:

```
.[]|{ single: .key }
```

Which produced:

```
{
  "single": "1"
}
{
  "single": "2"
}
```

Since each individual stream did not have the criteria to meet both attributes (`key=="1"` and `key=="2"`), each one got eliminated from each stream.  Sending the array through as a whole (`.|`) instead of as individual elements (`.[]|`) allowed both `select()`'s to behave as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
jq 'from_entries as $mapping |
    {one:"1", two:"2"}       |
    map_values($mapping[.])' input.json
```

This way, you can add more easily `three`, `four`,...